# Double dot notation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, range

I am working on a problem from RubyMonk called "[Kaprekar's Number](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/150-kaprekar-s-number)". For example, `9^2` is 81 and the result added is 9 again: `8 + 1 = 9`.

In a part of the problem they use a double dot notation that I don't really understand:

```
def kaprekar?(k)
  number_of_digits = k.to_s.size
  square_root = (k**2).to_s

  second_half = square_root[-number_of_digits..-1]
  first_half = square_root.size.even? ? square_root[0..number_of_digits-1] : square_root[0..number_of_digits-2]

  k == first_half.to_i + second_half.to_i
end
```

In `second_half` and `first_half`, for example, I know that `first_half` is a ternary operation "if?then:else", but what do `[-number_of_digits..-1]` or `[0..number_of_digits-1]` mean?

Is it a way to express ranges or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double-dot notation represents a Range.
So, for example, `1..10` would be like saying "from 1 up to 10".

When used with an array it usually represents a range of array-indexes.
So if you had `my_array[1..10]`, it would be "the elements of `my_array` with indexes from 1 up to 10."

When you use a negative number in an array-index range, it indicates a number that starts counting from the right-hand end of the array. Thus "-1" is the first array index from the right-hand-end.

So for your specific example: `square_root` is a string (which works a bit like an array of chars)... so `square_root[0..number_of_digits-1]` means "the characters in the `square_root` string from 0 (the beginning) up to `(number of digits - 1)`", and `square_root[number_of_digits..-1]` means "the characters in the `square_root` string, starting at `number_of_digits` and going up to the end of the string."

`square_root[0..number_of_digits-1]` and `square_root[number_of_digits..-1]` represent splitting the string in half at the point represented by `number_of_digits`.